# Phalcon Converting bound Parameter to String

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I have a Phalcon controller that builds a query to run against a model using bound parameters.  One of those parameters can be a varying number of integers in a statement like:

```
table.column IN(:bound:)
```

I've tried setting the bindType of said parameter to different bind types, but whenever I have a comma-delimited list of options:

```
$bind = '1234,2345,3456,4567'
```

It gets bound as a string in the query.  This problem does not occur when the parameter is a single number.  I have taken to testing whether the input is a single integer or a delimited string, and inserting the values manually if it is, but that seems inelegant.  Is there a way to have the Phalcon or the database send the raw value?  The parameters come from a session variable, so they are trusted values, but I escape them anyway.

Thanks

Comment: I do not think phalcon supports this semantic (like Zend does). You need to do that "manually".

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Query builder?

For example from within your controller/action:

```
$bind = '1234,2345,3456,4567';    
$resultset = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
               ->from('Namespace\Model')
               ->inWhere('column', explode(',', $bind))
               ->getQuery()
               ->execute();
```

More in de [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html) for the query builder.